# HideScrollAppBar Fragment Cannot be Converted to fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Guys After doing all the code exactly i'm getting this error can any one help me to out this issue.

Comment: Be more specific. What is HideScrollAppBar? Show your code

Comment: could you past your xml code !

Comment: Post your codes so that we can look into it and help